# Can someone provide a working code of loading data of text file to Label of kivy

Tags: python, kivy, label

I am able to get the data in main app class and run it to get as Label but when I want to do the same by getting data in main app class where as defining Label in another class, it's giving name error.

```
import kivy  
from kivy.app import App # import Kivy App module to create 
from kivy.uix.label import Label # import Label Module
  
kivy.require('1.11.1')  
  
class MyKivyApp(App): 
      
   def build(self): 
      f=open('tesit.txt','r')
      t=f.read()
      
      return Label(text =t)
   
   rt=MyKivyApp()
   rt.run()
```

Comment: Can you add the error you are getting?

Comment: I am geeting name_error:t is not defined

Comment: Code:import kivy
from kivy.app import App 
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.label import Label
Builder.load_string('''
<trip>:
    BoxLayout:
     Label:
      text:t
 ''')
class trip(Screen):
    pass
sm=ScreenManager()
sm.add_widget(trip(name='tr'))
class MyKivyApp(App):
    def build(self): 
         return sm
    def dreturn(self):
     f=open('tesit.txt','r')
        t=f.read()
rt=MyKivyApp()
rt.run()

Comment: What is the output of the error? Example: `Error 100: name_error the code on line X caused this error and has made something undefined.` Or something like that, I made that up, but you should be getting an output from somewhere.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your lines:

```
   rt=MyKivyApp()
   rt.run()
```

are inside the `MyKivyApp`. Just unindent those two lines to get them outside of the `App` class.

Comment: That is bcz of some prbln while copying the code. 

Answer (score 0):

This's how we can read a text file and display it as label in another screen in kivy.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import StringProperty

class Screen1(Screen):
    f=open('test.txt','r')
    t=f.readlines()
    b=t[0]
    f.close()

class Screen2(Screen):
    username = StringProperty("")


root = Builder.load_string('''

<Screen1>:
    name:'xy'
    id:loginscreen
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        Button:
            text:'Execution button'
            on_release: root.manager.current = "screen2"


<Screen2>:
    name: "screen2"
    FloatLayout:
        Label:
            text: root.username
        Button:
            text:'Back to menu'
            size_hint:.3,.3
            on_release: root.manager.current = "xy"

ScreenManager:
    Screen1:
        id:loginscreen
    Screen2:
        username: loginscreen.b

''')



class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return root
r=MyApp()
r.run()
```